# VueJs array of objects watcher not updating when object property changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects in my state like so:

```js
data() {
    return {
    users: [{id: 1, name: 'bob'}, {id: 2, name: 'bill'}]
    }
}
```

When I change the data like so:

```js
this.users[0].name = 'Mary'
```

A watcher that I have for the `students` property does not run, how do I make it run?

Comment: First there is nothing called `students` in your question (code) and second, there is no watcher ...(at least in your question)

Comment: See [Reactivity Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Answer (score 5):

Vue.js cannot detect mutations to array when you change any item or sub-field of a item using direct `index` access.

To do this, you can use `set` method of `Vue` object:

```
// Vue.set
const index = 0;
const newValue = { ...this.users[index], name: 'Mary' };

Vue.set(this.users, index, newValue);
```

Or, you can simply use manipulate array using `splice` method which is internally over-riden by Vue.js:

```
const index = 0;
const newValue = { ...this.users[index], name: 'Mary' };

// Using array manipulation
this.users.splice(index, 1, newValue);
```

Or, you can use **immutable data practice** as:

```
const newArray = [...this.users];
const newValue = { ...this.users[0], name: 'Mary' };
newArray[0] = newValue;

this.users = newArray;
```

Comment: Spent like 6 hours to find this. Thanks!